# Chaining predictions based on regression - overall goodness of fit?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling

Say I have a regression model for the relationship between variable *A* and variable *B*, as well as a second regression model for the relationship between *B* and a third variable *C*.

It seems intuitive that I could approximate *C* based on *A* by multiplying the coefficients from the two models. That is, if the first model stated that `B = A * 1.2` and the second that `C = B * 1.6`, I can substitute the terms to find that `C = A * 1.2 * 1.6`.

My question then, is about how I can calculate how *good* the combined model would be. Either in terms of the proportion of variance explained, or in terms of standard error, or some other measure of "goodness". It feels like there should be a way to combine some property of the two original models to derive some metric for the combined model.

Is there a theoretically sound way to do this?

Comment: just to understand the problem better: what prevens you from modelling C ~ A? the thing that prevents you from doing so could be informative about the appropriateness of your workaround

Comment: Good question. In practice there are a large number of models. The full set of permutations would be prohibitively time-consuming to calculate, but by introducing intermediate factors I can make it more manageable.

Comment: Well, consider there is an effect of A on C that runs through B, but also an *independent* effect of A on C. You approach will not pick up the latter, simply because knowledge of Cov(A,B) and Cov(B,C).is not sufficient to infer Cov(A,C). I'd strongly recommend to model the relationship between A and C directly, possibly taking into account mediation via B or B as a covariate, depending on what is theoretically sensible given the subject matter

Comment: I would normally agree, but in this instance the models are representing natural relationships and we have good evidence that there is no direct effect of A on C.

Comment: I see, others might know more here, but you can of course evaluate the predictive accuracy of your "algorithm" by a metric of choice like RMSE, AUC, etc. Not a "goodness of fit" though